# What is the main problem in this situation?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, version

```
(kivy_venv) C:\Users\Momin Khan Studio>python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.22 kivy_deps.glew==0.1.22
Collecting docutils
  Using cached docutils-0.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (570 kB)
Collecting pygments
  Using cached Pygments-2.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting pypiwin32
  Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.22 (from versions: 0.4.2, 0.4.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.22
```

Comment: Something else is limiting you to `kivy_deps.sdl2` 0.4.2 or 0.4.3 - which means 0.1.22 won't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

why you just don't easily by typing `python -m pip install kivy[base]` or install full kivy with `python -m pip install kivy[full]` even you can customize what you want by `python -m pip install kivy[base,media]` every of the examples automatically download what they need to work and you don't have to install dependencies manually